# Simulink Pid Block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm setting up a pid controller using simulink pid block where do I need to set a limitation(saturation) for pid parameters outputs. As you know, the "limit output" saturates on the total of "P+I+D" outputs but I need to set limitation on each "P" ,"I" and "D" parameters individually. More specifically on "D" outputs.

For this purpose I used the data type menus as shown in the picture but it doesnot work what ever I typed in the blanks. I tried to put the saturation block inside the mask but it is locked/forbidden.

Can anybody suggest how to limit the parameters outputs within pid block?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct settings. "Data type" allows you to set the data type (i.e. double, single, fixed-point, etc...) of the various signals inside the PID controller, it has nothing to do with saturating the output.

To do what you want, you need to select "Limit output" on the "PID Advanced" tab, which will allow to set 2 parameters, for the upper and lower limit. See screenshot below from the [PID documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pidcontroller.html):

[image]

See also [this example](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/anti-windup-control-using-a-pid-controller.html) with saturation.

Comment: "limit output" saturates on the total of "P+I+D" outputs. I want to set limitation on each "P" ,"I" and "D" parameters individually. More specifically on "D" output.

Comment: You should have made this clear in your question. I don't believe that's possible with the standard PID block, you probably need to create your own custom block.